# How to change the format of a path string to a different OS?

Tags: python, path, operating-system

I need to change a file path from MAC to Windows and I was about to just do a simple `.replace()` of any `/` with `\` but it occurred to me that there may be a better way. So for example I need to change:

```
foo/bar/file.txt
```

to:

```
foo\bar\file.txt
```

Comment: the `os` module has some support.  see `os.path.join` for example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this:

```
>>> s = '/foo/bar/zoo/file.ext'
>>> import ntpath
>>> import os
>>> s.replace(os.sep,ntpath.sep)
'\\foo\\bar\\zoo\\file.ext'
```

Answer (score 10):

The [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module (introduced in Python 3.4) has support for this:

```py
from pathlib import PureWindowsPath, PurePosixPath

# Windows -> Posix
win = r'foo\bar\file.txt'
posix = str(PurePosixPath(PureWindowsPath(win)))
print(posix)  # foo/bar/file.txt

# Posix -> Windows
posix = 'foo/bar/file.txt'
win = str(PureWindowsPath(PurePosixPath(posix)))
print(win)  # foo\bar\file.txt
```

Comment: For the conversion to posix path this is also an option: `posix = PureWindowsPath(win).as_posix()`

Answer (score 3):

**Converting to Unix:**

```
import os
import posixpath
p = "G:\Engineering\Software_Development\python\Tool"
p.replace(os.sep, posixpath.sep)
```

This will replace the used-os separator to Unix separator.

**Converting to Windows:**

```
import os
import ntpath
p = "G:\Engineering\Software_Development\python\Tool"
p.replace(os.sep, ntpath.sep)
```

This will replace the used-os separator to Windows separator.

Answer (score 0):

since path is actually a string, you can simply use following code:

```
p = '/foo/bar/zoo/file.ext'
p = p.replace('/', '\\')
```

output:

```
'\\foo\\bar\\zoo\\file.ext'
```

Answer (score -1):

`os.path.join` will intelligently join strings to form filepaths, depending on your OS-type (`POSIX`, `Windows`, `Mac OS`, etc.)

**Reference**: http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join

For your example:

```
import os

print os.path.join("foo", "bar", "file.txt")
```

Comment: the problem is that I start with the full string 'foo/bar/file.txt' not a list of folders...