# Convert module path to import_module name format

Tags: python-3.x, python-importlib

Is there a built-in or simple way to convert a file path (module path) to a `name` argument to be used by the [importlib.import_module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) function?

For example:

```
'path/module.py' -> 'path.module'
```

I could do something like this:

```py
if path.endswith('.py'):
    path = path[:-3]

path = path.replace('/', '.')
```

But I was looking for a simpler way.

Answer (score 1):

Would:

```
path.split('.py')[0].replace("/", ".")
```

be suitable?

Comment: This example is more concise and will probably do the job, but I was looking for a built-in function that does it and that will probably deal with corner cases (maybe related to the os). Anyway, if there is no such thing, this answer will help, thanks.

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14360389/getting-file-path-from-command-line-argument-in-python/47324233) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52593420/python-convert-windows-file-path-in-a-variable) help?